# How to match the first element with exact contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four anchor elements with the contents of "taw", "wat", "wat 2, and "wat". Is there a way to select only the first element that contains "wat"?

I have this so far:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "wat";
}).css("font-weight", "bold");
```

And it is selecting the second and last elements. I only wish to select the first element containing "wat". Thank you!

Demo: https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/jOOZeGZ?editors=1010

Comment: While there are better ways, I'd just point out something very fundamental. Your code is producing an array-like list of elements. If you want the first one, you can always grab it by index. While I wouldn't use jQuery, you could simply add `.eq(0)` before the `.css()` call.

Comment: That said, it makes more sense to stop the DOM selection as soon as a match is found instead of selecting all `a` elements from the DOM and then filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.first()`

```js
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "wat";
}).first().css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`.first()`**](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to ***reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set***:

```js
$(".myDiv").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "wat";
}).first().css("font-weight", "bold");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">taw</div>
<div class="myDiv">wat</div>
<div class="myDiv">wat 2</div>
<div class="myDiv">wat</div>
```

Comment: They want exact match. If the `wat 2` element was first your demo would be broken.

Comment: @Kaiido, I missed the part *it is selecting the second and last elements*........thanks:)